# Azure build fail with TFS hosted buildserver: Windows Azure Tools\2.0\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found

Tags: azure, tfs, continuous-integration, build-server

Im new to Azure and wanted to create a Continuous Integration build using TFS. I created a build definition but building my Cloud App with simple website using a hosted buildserver in the build definition fails with error:

> C:\a\src\myAzure\myAzure\myAzure.ccproj (70): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.0\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I can however build locally, and manually Publish to Azure and it will deploy fine.
Im suspecting that the hosted buildserver of TFS does not support Azure 2.0?
Is there a way around this problem or will I have to forget the idea of using CI?

Comment: same thing here, cant believe this is happening, we have several teams depending on it

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be so since the Build is a preview feature of the Team Foundation Service. There was the same thing with Azure SDK 1.8, but they updated the Build Servers in a couple of days. Hope that it will not take long this time.

UPDATE:
"No, TF Service hosted build machines do not have the new SDK 2.0 at this time. We expect all users to have Azure SDK 2.0 support **post June 1st**. In the meantime you will need to use an on-prem build controller with the bits you need and deploy to Azure from there." 
(C) Trevor Hancock from Microsoft
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuretfs/thread/2df796d5-1abb-4b89-a571-0b7a62b80d55

UPDATE 2:
I've managed to complete a successful build using TFS build servers with SDK 2.0 So I think this problem is resolved for now. In future I recommend not to do updates to new versions of Azure SDK until the TFS build servers are ready.

Comment: Ok Thanks dygo for confirming my suspicion. I guess I have to wait now and see. Sigh, imagine my disappointment when I learned about Azure and how easy it would be to integrate with TFS and set up CI, and then incompatible versions between TFSpreview and Azure stopped me....

Comment: The good news is that setting up on on-prem build server isn't that hard. I ran into this issue as well when upgrading to v1.8 of the SDK so I've had a build machine running locally since then. After my upgrade to the v2 SDK on the build machine, my local builds started working fine again. It's livable, at least until they upgrade Azure to the v2 SDK.

Comment: Since this issue is not yet solved by TFS/Microsoft team, any advice on getting started with a free on-premise build server?